# Error while importing data into a DB2 Database

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-luw

I have tried to load data into DB2 database from csv file.

I have used SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD.

My csv file

```
11246,209,-1,"VERDE","Prueba","VERDE","MIGRACION","MIGRACION",'2020-05-20 00:00:00','2020-05-20 00:00:00'
```

I am calling :

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD( 'IMPORT FROM "/home/wvillega/Prueba.csv" OF DEL MESSAGES ON SERVER INSERT INTO LEASING.GENCATALOGOS' );
```

System Returned:

> IWAQ0003W SQL warnings were found SQLState=01H52 Routine
>   "SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD" execution has completed, but at least one error,
>   "SQL3015", was encountered during the execution. More information is
>   available.. SQLCODE=20397, SQLSTATE=01H52, DRIVER=4.19.56

Answer (score 0):

[IMPORT command using the ADMIN_CMD procedure](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023575.html)

When you specify MESSAGES ON SERVER, the routine returns a result set described at the link above in the following table:
*Table 1. Result set returned by the IMPORT command*
This means, that you should process this result set and use the following columns (there are ready-to-use statements in these columns):

- MSG_RETRIEVAL column to retrieve the corresponding messages
- MSG_REMOVAL column to remove these messages